# nodejs mongoose many-to-many relation on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, many-to-many

I'm trying to make a many-to-many relation between two documents in mongoose. Just can't make it work.

I've been trying to utilize the mongoose `populate` method, but with no success. Does anyone know any good tutorials or example on how to take on the matter?

Update:

Got schemas

```
var EventSchema = new Schema({
    users: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }]
});
```

and

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    events: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Event'
    }]
});
```

In my tests I pused to `event` model `user` like so

```
    event.users.push(user);
    event.save(function(err, doc) {
      user.events[0].should.equal(event._id);
      done();
    });
```

firstly I need to push somehow saved event to added user to event. Then by using populate I should can 'dress up' every object in `events` array and `users` array. Preferably in `post save` callback, if I understood populate correctly.

This test pases

```
  it('creates', function(done) {
    event.users.append(user);
    event.save(function(err, ev) {
      user.save(function(err, doc) {
        doc.events[0].should.equal(ev._id);
        doc.populate('events', function(err, d) {
          console.log(d);
          done();
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

So I know the ids are stored correctly, but when I run `doc.populate()` the returned document has `events` array empty. Just don't get it.

Comment: Is there already large volume of existing data that makes MongoDB a requirement?  If not, why not use a relational database?  And if you aren't having success, this site is probably best for figuring out why your `populate` code doesn't work...can you post what you've done so folks can suggest answers to the core issue?

Comment: I've found a plugin that sort of makes the realation thingy for me... Dunno if I'll be able to get out of it what I need, though. I've have had so many changes, that I don't remember which was closest, but I'll show what I've got (without the plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it work... used `mongo-relation` package to add the needed ids for me, but docs for this plugin made me change the schema form

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  events: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Event'
  }]
});
```

to

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  events: [Schema.ObjectId]
});
```

once corrected, it worked.